# Is it possible to create a v-class Vue directive that can be overridden by parent just like regular :class prop?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Please see this minimum example

I have a `Child.vue` and `Parent.vue` which look like this

```html
<!-- Child.vue -->
<template>
  <div :class="'bg-gray text-white'">I'm Child</div>
</template>
```

```html
<template>
  <Child class="p-4" />
</template>

<script>
  import Child from "./Child.vue";

  export default {
    components: {
      Child,
    },
  };
</script>

<style>
  .p-4 {
    padding: 16px;
  }

  .bg-gray {
    background: gray;
  }

  .text-white {
    color: white;
  }
</style>
```

The final class name for `Child.vue` wrapper element will be `bg-gray text-white p-4`, class names are all merged.

However, I would like to create a `v-class` directive and make my API looks like this

```html
<!-- Child.vue -->
<template>
  <div v-class="'bg-gray text-white'">I'm Child</div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    directives: {
      class: {
        inserted(el, binding) {
          const css = String.raw; // Not doing anything right now.

          el.className = css`
            ${binding.value}
          `;
        },
      },
    },
  };
</script>
```

And `Parent.vue` stays the same.

Now the final merged class name is `bg-gray text-white`, `p-4` is missing!

How can I preserve `p-4` just like I'm using regular :class prop?

---

My use case is I want to use the tagged template literal function in my Vue template.

However, Vue doesn't support template literal function in the template, the compiler will yell!

For example

```html
<div :class="css`text`"></div>
```

Comment: do you mean template literal function the  ````${some logic}```` syntax?

Comment: `<div :class="css\`text\`"></div>` This will yell in Vue, css is coming from any kind of popular css-in-js package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out to push the value to the class list :

```
el.classList.add( css`
        ${binding.value}
      `);
```